# How to get value of string created in resources Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an android application in Xamarin studios and want to make a text of a button underlined. I created a string in strings.xml like the following

```
 <string name="Advanced_Search"><u>Advanced Search</u></string>
```

I was succesfully able to reference this string in the xml file for the desginer, however I want to access it in code to set it as a button's text. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
advancedSearchButton.Text = Resource.String.Advanced_Search.ToString();
```

When i try to reference the string like that i get an integer value for the string, but I actually want the text that the string holds. How can I access the string like that in Xamarin using c#?

Comment: Alright I see what you are saying. I will delete the android tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`Resources.GetString`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetString/p/System.Int32/):

```
advancedSearchButton.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Advanced_Search);
```

This is assuming the code is contained within an `Activity`, otherwise you need to have a reference to an Android [`Context`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Context/).

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that the Build Action of the string.xml file is another, in which case the Resource.Desginer file which is where it is referenced by an ID is not created, select the file and see the properties, the Build Action must be AndroidResource .

Compile the project again, now the id of the string should appear and you can convert it to a string with ToString ()

Answer (score 0):

In your string.xml you should add:

```
<string name="UrlPrivacyPolicy">http://www.yoururl.com</string>
```

Then you can try with:

```
string text = Application.Context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.UrlPrivacyPolicy);
```